# Difference between discriminated Union types in F#

Tags: f#

I'm reading about F# and looking at people's source code and I sometimes see

```
Type test =
   | typeone
   | typetwo
```

And sometimes i see

```
type test = typeone | typetwo
```

One of them has a pipe before and the one doesn't. At first I thought one was an enum vs discriminated Union but I THINK they are the same. Can someone explain the difference if there is any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. These notations are completely equivalent. The leading pipe character is optional.

Having this first pipe optional helps make the code look nicer in different circumstances. In particular, if my type has many cases, and each case has a lot of data, it makes sense to put them on separate lines. In this case, the leading pipe makes them look visually aligned, so that the reader perceives them as a single logical unit:

```
type Large =
  | Case1 of int * string
  | Case2 of bool
  | SomeOtherCase
  | FinalCase of SomeOtherType
```

On the other hand, if I only need two-three cases, I can put them on one line. In that case, the leading pipe only gets in the way, creating a feeling of clutter:

```
type QuickNSmall = One | Two | Three
```

Comment: You should add a note about the fact that F# was ported from ML and that it is a hold over from ML. See [ML spec](http://sml-family.org/sml97-defn.pdf) page 11.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference.

In the spec, the first `|` is optional.

The relevant bit of the spec is this:

> union-type-cases:=   '|'opt union-type-case '|' ... '|'
>   union-type-case

An enum would needs to give explicit values to the cases like

```
Type test =
   | typeone = 1
   | typetwo = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the leading `|` is optional.

The examples in the other answers do not show this, so it is worth adding that you can omit it even for a multi-line discriminated union (and include it when defining a single line union):

```
type Large =
    Case1 of int * string
  | Case2 of bool
  | SomeOtherCase
  | FinalCase of SomeOtherType

type QuickNSmall = | One | Two | Three
```

I think most people just find these ugly (myself included!) and so they are usually written the way you see in the other answers.